# Initialization of a global variable that refers to a global variable in different file

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I'm working with a project that has code roughly similar to this, all of this in a single library:

```
// a.cpp
static bool map_exists;

int GetMappedValue(int value)
{
   if (!map_exists)
   {
      map_exists = true;
      // various initialization code that initializes SomeMap
   }

   return SomeMap.Get(value);
};
```

```
/// b.cpp
const int mapped_value = GetMappedValue(3);
```

Unlike the Meyer singleton which is quite well described in terms of safety, it's not clear to me this is safe. I would like to get a clear understanding of why this is/is not safe - what I fear could happen is that for example `map_exists` is not guaranteed to be initialized by the time `mapped_value` is being initialized.

//

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization `mapped_value` will not be statically initialized as constant initialization is not applicable (`GetMappedValue` is not marked as constexpr) so it will be zero initialized, while `map_exists` is guaranteed to be statically initialized.

However, there's still the possibility of an early dynamic initialization, which could cause issues, as if the compiler would decide to do early dynamic initialization of `mapped_value`, there's no guarantee it will be initialized after `map_exists`, at least from what I can tell.

> Early dynamic initialization
> The compilers are allowed to initialize dynamically-initialized variables as part of static initialization (essentially, at compile time), if the following conditions are both true:
>
> the dynamic version of the initialization does not change the value of any other object of namespace scope prior to its initialization
> the static version of the initialization produces the same value in the initialized variable as would be produced by the dynamic initialization if all variables not required to be initialized statically were initialized dynamically.

The first condition is not violated - dynamic initialization of `mapped_value` does change `map_exists`, but `map_exists` is guaranteed to be statically initialized before that happens.

I'm not so sure about the second condition though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is guaranteed to work [by the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.start.static#2):

> Constant initialization is performed if a variable or temporary object with static or thread storage duration is constant-initialized ([expr.const]). If constant initialization is not performed, a variable with static storage duration ([basic.stc.static]) or thread storage duration ([basic.stc.thread]) is zero-initialized ([dcl.init]). Together, zero-initialization and constant initialization are called static initialization; all other initialization is dynamic initialization. All static initialization strongly happens before ([intro.races]) any dynamic initialization.

`map_exists` will be initialized by static initialization, and it will be zero-initialized. Thus, its value will be `false`. `mapped_value` will be zero-initialized, then undergo dynamic initialization. But as the last sentence states, this happens after all static initialization. So `map_exists` will be zero initialized before `GetMappedValue` needs to run.

Cppreference is merely talking about how the compiler is allowed to implement things. Under the "as if" rule, a compiler can do "dynamic initialization" at compile time and store that value in the executable/library, under the condition that the results behave "as if" it happened as required by the standard.

Comment: So while "The compilers are allowed to initialize dynamically-initialized variables as part of static initialization (essentially, at compile time)" by applying early dynamic initialization, it is still technically dynamic initialization as far the initializing ordering guarantees, is that correct?